# Regex For Custom Date Input

Tags: jquery, regex, date-format

We need to validate input which would allow only specific date format.

mm/dd/yyyy-mm/dd/yyyy,mm/dd/yyyy-mm/dd/yyyy,mm/dd/yyyy-mm/dd/yyyy and so on.....

Example:

01/25/2017-01/27/2017,02/25/2017-02/27/2017,03/25/2017-03/27/2017,04/21/2017-04/22/2017,04/28/2017-04/29/2017.....

Comment: catching that long input as a string isn't ideal. You should separate the date strings, per date or range, and comma-concatenate them after validation.

Comment: Where is the code you tried? -- Regex won't be usefull at all. Look for [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @Stavm, yes I know that but I need to go with this in my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you have a number of **date ranges** (2 dates, formatted as *mm/dd/yyyy*, separated with a "-").

To capture each date in a range you can use 2 capturing groups:

```
/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})-(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/g
```

Each consecutive match contains both dates, captured in group 1 and 2.

Then it is your task to "consume" both groups, starting from validation
whether month/day/year part taken together are a proper date.

This validation should be performed with other tools.
E.g. date parsing function, called with improper date string
should raise an exception.